# How does is_active work and is it necessary for bcrypt?

Tags: php, cakephp, bcrypt

I am learning how to use bcrypt to encrypt my users passwords instead of the default cakephp method, and a question I ran into is;

what's the point of 'User.is_active'?

Specifically from;

```
'Auth' => array(
        'authenticate' => array(
            'Blowfish' => array(
                'scope' => array('User.is_active' => true)
                )
            ),
```

My users table does not have a is_active table, and even if I added it, what would I populate it? A value? a integer? When would I populate it? When the users registers?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`is_active` is a column of table users, it's a logic flag, that means - allow only users with `is_active = true`
`scope` parameter - is not required